# Find smallest sum of values in matrix using row index and colum index once

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, matrix, optimization

So I want to find the smallest values in a matrix in the following way.

```
       [[ 1000.   930.   940.   740.]
        [ 1000.  1000.   990.   670.]
   M1=  [ 1000.  1000.  1000.   680.]
        [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.]]
```

The sum of 2 matrix values should be chosen in such a way that the indexes are used once 0,1,2,3. But also the sum of matrix values should be minimized.

So in this case the solution would be `M1[2][3]` and `M1[0][1]`.
Incorrect would be `M1[2][3]` and `M1[1][3]`, which hase a lower sum but is does not contain unique index numbers.

The solution should work for NxN matrices, N is even. So for 8x8 matrix, i want to find 4 elements. So that the index Numbers. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are uses once. So four matrix values. 
Another constraint is that the matrix contains only values of intrest in the upper trangle matrix. So were the matrix elements are 1000, these elements can be ignored in finding the minimum sum.

I have tried to alter the Hungarian algorithm, but this was not successful.
Does anybody know of an algorithm that does what I want? Maybe a python package wich I can abuse

Or has a smart solution which would help, I have to do this matrix with about 200X200 elements max.

Comment: is this a theoretical question or an exam? or a real problem? is there some constraint on the data like a sparse matrix or big differences in values? simple brute force picking does not sound promising for n=200.

Comment: Its a diagonaal matrix, as in the  example. Its for a personal project, were i want to minimize the differecence between multiple objects.

Comment: that diagonal constraint may help. i think when you add the transposed matrix you could use the hungarian algorithm. you search for a one to one assignment with the constraints that m[i][j] requires m[j][i].

Comment: @stefan Yeah just mirror the matrix on the diagonal, I could do that. thanks:)

Answer (score -1):

I will say a solution that is probably not the fastest but it may work.

You can build a graph this way:

- the graph will contain (N×N+1) vertexes, which represent the indexes of the matrix and a new one, which will be the **source**
- the source will be connected to all other vertexes with a distance equivalent to the value of the index each of them represents.
- then you must connect each vertex (except the source) to every other vertex that is possible to go to (for example, M1[1][2] can go to M1[0][3] but not to M1[1][3]). The distance from any vertex to a vertex V will correspond to the value of V in the matrix.

after you build this graph, you should walk on it K steps (being K the number of possible matrix' indexes you will consider, for example, 2 in a 4x4 matrix like your example).

For each step you take, you store in a stack and in 2 hashes the last position you were (the first to store all rows already used, the second to store all columns already used) and you mark the vertex you get into.

Always you get into a vertex, you should check if is possible to stay in it by using the hashes (theoretically O(1) checking), and if is possible, you add that value to the current sum, otherwise you go to the previous position (stored in the stack) and remove the weight you added when you went into the current vertex.

You should also store a global variable and always you walk K steps, you check if the current sum is smaller than the global sum, and if it is, you change it.

After you walk all possible ways, the global sum will be your answer.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: that is called depth first search. if i got it right for a matrix n=100 the number of possible combinations exceeds the number of atoms in the universe. by a million millions. not to mention n=200 :-)